# Submit HTML Form to a PHP file from an ASP.NET Core page

Tags: c#, php, html, asp.net-core, http-post

I have created an `ASP.NET` Core application and have a checkout page that needs to post the HTML form to a PHP file.

The problem is that model binding will post back to the Controller - Action that served the page. Is there a way to post an HTML form to a PHP file, for processing, from `ASP.NET Core` page?

The Form looks like this:

```
<form action="processor.php" method="post">
</form>
```

Serviced by:
Controller: `Store`
Action: `Checkout`

As you may know, the model binder will post back to the `Store Controller` but will throw an exception as it expects to find an Action named `processor.php` which does not exist.

Is there a workaround to this?

I want to process the posted data in the **PHP file**.

Comment: I think you can create a custom class that inherits the Controller (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-controller-cs).  Then modify so the input is the text output from the PHP instead of the HTML that is returned in the response.

Comment: @jdweng: Can you show by a code example? You seem to suggest that input is coming from PHP and form in submitted to the model action.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-an-action-cs

Comment: @jdweng: "Creating an Action (C#)" is the title of the article. It is not relevant to my issue. I do not want to create Controller Actions. I want to post to a PHP file not send back to the NET CORE backend

Comment: You want to parse a response.  The two main way of doing this is to either use a controller with an Action or parse the HTML with a library like the HTML Utility Pack.

Comment: I have not yet found a solution, still open. Direct linking to the PHP file is generating a 4040 file not found error.

Comment: I think you mean error 404 (not 4040).  The server cannot find a file.  Either the path for file location is wrong on the server (you may need full pathname) or you do not have credentials to access the file on the server.  Is yuor code executing your webpage on the server.  The server has a method for capturing all port 80 messages and the error is being returned by server before your app is being called.

Comment: @jdweng: I made a typo, I meant 404 you are right. The website is making an internal linking. The file exists on the web server. I have placed the file in a public folder (httpdocs) which means it should be a public file. I think the pathname may be wrong as you mentioned. I will ask my host provider for the full pathname. I was accessing it like this https://www.website.com/publicdirectory/file.php and still I get 404. I thought public folders do not need any permissions to be accessed. I am asking my host provider for the full pathname and will come back with results

Comment: My Host provider said the httpdocs is the public folder and I should try to access files in visual studio then upload. But that is exactly what is not working. I hope to experiement until I find a solution

Comment: I client on has GUEST priviledges on server and doesn't have access to the file system.  See Roles : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs

Comment: I think you misunderstood my scenario. The website should post a form to a local PHP page in a public directory (httpdocs). There is no role based authorization necessary. When I tested this with pure HTML it worked by direct linking e.g. website.com/directory/file.php but with asp.net core it seems like the server is processing the request as website.com/controller/action etc. This leads to 404. I am not looking for a way to correctly POST to the PHP file.